# What does "っこしよ？” mean in a kyoto accent?

Tags: translation

Just read in manga someone with a kyoto accent say

> "とりあいっこしよか？"

I'm wondering if this is just "取り合い" while the "っこしよか" is an accent thing? (if so what does it do?)
Or is it a different word entirely?

Comment: could you add some context? who is saying this to whom and what's the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is `っこ` by itself. It seems to be a suffix used in child speech and is somewhat analogous to the ~合う suffix in the meaning "each other" ([Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93)). Some examples:

- にらめっこ : staring contest (from 睨{にら}む = stare, glare at)
- 洗{あら}いっこ: washing (somebody else's body); scrubbing each other
- ごっこ: a children's game with two or more participants (e.g. 鬼{おに}ごっこ = tag, ママごっこ = playing house, 戦争{せんそう}ごっこ = playing soldiers)

It's also seen without this meaning in other child speech or words used to talk to chidren:

- おしっこ(する): pee, wee-wee
- だっこ(する): hug, hold (a baby)

In your example っこ seems somewhat redundant since 取り合い already includes that meaning so possibly it was used for a playful or childish tone. It's not specific to Kyoto or Kansai speech. And ~しよか is just ~しようか (shall we ~?).