# What is the origin of っこない?

Tags: etymology, expressions, suffixes

There's a construction V+っこない which means something like "have no way of doing V".

> お前には分かりっこないでしょう。
>
> There's no way you would understand.

Is it known what this construction originates from? I can't find any reliable information either in Japanese or English.

Comment: Don't think でしょう really matches お前 here.

Comment: This でしょう seems saying “betcha”. *I betcha/bet you can’t understand it.* I don't know the explanation of っこない though.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6836/what-does-%e9%80%83%e3%81%92%e3%81%a3%e3%81%93%e3%81%aa%e3%81%97%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%82%88%e3%81%86-mean/6837#6837

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/72432/ -- that post includes a link to the [JA Wiktionary entry](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%93) with a relevant definition: 「3. 動詞の連用形に付いて、お互いにしあったり、勝敗を競ったりすることを表す。通常、ひらがなで書く。」

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are not asking for the historical origin, the uncontracted form of 'っこない' is 'こと**は**ない'. Your sentence becomes お前には分かることはないでしょう

こと means here something like event or situation, so ' V + ことはない' (more) literally means that the situation where *V* happens is impossible. Hence, the construction means 'there is no way ...', as you already see.

===

Among the posts linked in the comment, 逃げっこなし is basically the same (逃げることはなし) and the second っこ for reciprocal actions is different.

===

ことない mentioned in other answers is possible but has different meanings. Either a simple negative sentence or meaning that someone goes beyond a reasonable limit. For example,

そんなに怒る**ことない**でしょう - You don't have to get that angry (about such small matters)

Comment: Wouldn't そんなに怒ることはないでしょう mean the same thing?

Comment: ＠Simon Yes, that would mean the same. Also ..怒ること**も**ないでしょう would mean the same.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve always thought っこない originates from ことない.